# Mysql dump to sqlite android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am doing some R&D work on restoring data from a `MySQL(.sql)` dump file to `sqlite database`.I had success fully  restored all the data using a `buffer reader` to my sqlite, but is taking more time than web api sync. My question is can we directly  restore a SQL dump to sqlite like restore a data base in android.